# If $U,W$ are subspaces of vector space $V$, show that $U\cap W$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Proposition.** If $U,W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, show that $U\cap W$.

Proof. Since $O\in U$ and $O\in W$, we have $O\in U\cap W$. If
$v,m \in U\cap W$, then $v,m \in U$ so $v+m \in U$ and $vm \in W$, hence
$v+m \in W$. Thus $v,m$ belongs to $U\cap W$. Similarly, $cv$, belongs to
$U$ and $W$, so $cv \in U\cap W$. Consequently, Un $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

My question is:  ''If $v,m \in U\cap W$, then $v,m \in U$ so $v+m \in U$.'' Why $v+m \in U$? It can not be, can it?

Comment: Do you mean "show that $U\cap W$ is a subspace?"

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes. Edited.

Comment: The reason $v+m\in U$ is that both $v\in U$ and $m\in U$, and $U$ is by hypothesis a subspace, so is closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is closed under addition, so any sum of vectors in $U$ is a vector in $U$

Answer (score 0):

> ''If $v,m \in U\cap W$, then $v,m \in U$ so $v+m \in U$.'' Why $v+m \in U$? It can not be, can it?

It must, by assumption that $U$ is a subspace if $v,m \in U$ but their sum is not in $U$.... but then contradicting that $U$ is a subspace.

Otherwise we just have found two vectors such that it disproves the closure under addition property of subspaces... thus $U$ is not a subspace as previously assumed.